# How to count visitors from the same network to my website in PHP?

Tags: php, count, ip, visitors

Now I am developing a web site of which it's owner wants to know how many unique visitors visited it. I don't want the number of visits or clicks. If 5 students in a university visits the site from 5 different computers, but from the same network, which means they have same IP address .. How can I specify them as 5 different people ??

I need to know the idea how to do that.

I found this solution :

```
<?php
md5(
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);
// 80b567b7c7ccfbda75a9712f16ca4429
```

Is it reliable or there is a better way ??

Comment: That's not even remotely reliable, they can have the same user agent as well

Comment: what the way to do that then ?

Comment: Try using session or cookies, set session value on someone's visit and if on another visit that value exists that means its the same person most probably  (still not 100%)